# Difference between boost::scoped_ptr<T> and std::unique_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, scoped-ptr

Is the sole difference between `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>` the fact that `std::unique_ptr<T>` has move semantics whereas `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` is just a get/reset smart pointer?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No, but that is the most important difference.

The other major difference is that `unique_ptr` can have a destructor object with it, similarly to how `shared_ptr` can. Unlike `shared_ptr`, the destructor type is part of the `unique_ptr`'s type (the way allocators are part of STL container types).

A `const unique_ptr` can effectively do most of what a `scoped_ptr` can do; indeed, unlike `scoped_ptr`, a `const unique_ptr` cannot be rebound with a `reset` call.

Also, `unique_ptr<T>` can work on a `T` which is an incomplete type. The default deleter type requires that `T` be complete when you do anything to the `unique_ptr` that potentially invokes the deleter. You therefore have some freedom to play games about where that happens, depending on the situation.

Comment: Does `boost::scoped_ptr` require a fully defined type like `unique_ptr`?

Comment: So, the functionality chain would be scoped_ptr ->[custom del/alloc + move semantics]-> unique_ptr ->[copy semantics]-> shared_ptr?

Comment: Michael, `unique_ptr` does not require a fully defined type—only the constructor/destructor do. This makes it usable for pimpl.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: `unique_ptr` doesn't require a fully defined type. `unique_ptr`'s destructor does. So does the destructor of a `scoped_ptr`. If you make one a member of a class, you can just give that class a destructor which is implemented in the .cpp file rather than the header.

Comment: @moshbear: I'd say the functionality chain is "don't use `scoped_ptr` anymore." `unique_ptr` can do everything a `scoped_ptr` can do and more. A `const unique_ptr` is a `scoped_ptr`, but better. So really, there's no point in using `scoped_ptr` unless your compiler doesn't support `unique_ptr`. The fewer pointer templates you have, the better.

Comment: There's one case where `scoped_ptr` is more useful than `const unique_ptr`: you can't reset pointers in `const unique_ptr`, but if the pointer is already at class scope, I might as well use regular `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @NicolBolas maybe you could shift your comments on `unique_ptr` accepting incomplete types and `const unique_ptr` being a better `scoped_ptr` to your answer. I was about to add it as an amendment to your answer until I saw the comments. I think these are quite important facts. Nice answer regardless.

Answer (score 36):

`unique_ptr` owns an object exclusively.It is **non-copyable** but supports **transfer-of-ownership**. It was introduced as replacement for the now deprecated `auto_ptr`.

`scoped_ptr` is **neither copyable nor movable**. It is the preferred choice when you want to make sure pointers are deleted when going out of scope.

Comment: I thought the preferred choice when you want to make sure that pointers are deleted at the end of a scope was `unique_ptr<T> const`.

Comment: A bit late, but I think scoped_ptr does communicate the intention that a ptr must be deleted on scope exit more than unique_ptr. A unique_ptr can be moved out of a scope.

Comment: @BrandonKohn: scoped_ptr supports `swap`, so it can also escape the scope. (Actually I have no idea why scoped_ptr forbids move but allows swap; this seems an inconsistency in the design.)