# Which header should be used for using scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, scoped-ptr

I want to use smart pointer in my c++ application.

Which header file I should include for using std scoped_ptr?

Comment: May I know the reason for vote down

Comment: `scoped_ptr` is not a standard smart pointer, it is [provided by Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/scoped_ptr.html). C++11 introduced `std::unique_ptr`, which is similar to `scoped_ptr` with the exception that it is movable. As to the headers where these can be found, this information can very easily be found in the respective documentations.

Comment: I downvoted your question because it does not show any research effort: the StackOverflow users are not a replacement for documentation, where you could have found this information.

Comment: For the differences between `boost::scoped_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8199812/20984) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3019512/20984).

Comment: @LucTouraille Please see this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) Here, something std::tr1::scoped_ptr is mentioned in Lloyd's answer

Comment: @Lloyd's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/106614/981959) is wrong, there is no `std::tr1::scoped_ptr`

Comment: @LucTouraille Actually, the boost docs don't explicitly say which header file to use: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm - it's buried in example code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no scoped_ptr in the standard C++ library. All [C++11 smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) are in header `<memory>`. If you want [boost::scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) then you need `boost/scoped_ptr.hpp`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `scoped_ptr` in the namespace `std`.
You can either use `boost::scoped_ptr` from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).
Or I guess you wanted `std::unique_ptr`.In this case you need to include `<memory>`

Answer (score 2):

`scoped_ptr` is a part of [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/), not standard library.