# What is called a scope pointer in C++ ?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was asked this in an interview. Seems boost library has something called scoped_pointer. Not sure if he asked about that.

Comment: "scope pointer" or "scoped pointer"?

Comment: Well a pointer can't address a scope, so scoped_ptr sounds like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: "What is called a scope pointer in C++ ?" -- Is that the question you were asked verbatim? I'm guessing not and I'd guess they were asking about smart pointers and RAII in general (perhaps `std::unique_ptr` specifically) ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199812/difference-between-boostscoped-ptrt-and-stdunique-ptrt

Comment: Worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c

Comment: @JamesAdkison I'll bet the verbatim question was asked in another language, and he's translating for our benefit.

Comment: @Barmar Valid point, quite possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost does have a `scoped_ptr`.

**Boost Docs**

> The primary reason to use scoped_ptr rather than auto_ptr is to let readers of your code know that you intend "resource acquisition is initialization" >to be applied only for the current scope, and have no intent to transfer ownership.
>
> A secondary reason to use scoped_ptr is to prevent a later maintenance programmer from adding a function that transfers ownership by returning the auto_ptr, because the maintenance programmer saw auto_ptr, and assumed ownership could safely be transferred.
>
> Think of bool vs int. We all know that under the covers bool is usually just an int. Indeed, some argued against including bool in the C++ standard because of that. But by coding bool rather than int, you tell your readers what your intent is. Same with scoped_ptr; by using it you are signaling intent.
>
> It has been suggested that scoped_ptr is equivalent to std::auto_ptr const. Ed Brey pointed out, however, that reset will not work on a std::auto_ptr const.

Answer (score 1):

The term most probably referred to the c++ [smart-pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) category, which provides scoped owner management for pointers.